# How does nodejistu private npm decide if a module should be private?

Tags: npm, nodejitsu

Does every module I publish to `https://<private>.registry.nodejitsu.com/` become private?

I assumed the [`private` package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#private) flag would play into it, but I just published a module intended for NPM to nodejitsu, configured as my default registry [as recommended](https://www.nodejitsu.com/getting-started-with-npm/#extended-config), and it got trapped as a private module.

Answer (score 1):

After a chat with nodejitsu support, yep, they're all private.  Publish public modules directly to npmjs.org:

```
$ npm publish --registry="http://registry.npmjs.org"
```